# Spring Jedis. SCAN and KEYS keys mismatch

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I put in redis a key-value, where key is UUID converted to a byte array, for space optimization.

```
"3DEBB752-654A-4206-89BA-D3517237312E" -> [-119, -70, -45, 81, 114, 55, 49, 46, 61, -21, -73, 82, 101, 74, 66, 6].
```

I'm using Spring Jedis to get data from Redis server and when I try to get key via `KEYS` function

```
jedisConnection.keys("*".getBytes());
```

I get

```
[-119, -70, -45, 81, 114, 55, 49, 46, 61, -21, -73, 82, 101, 74, 66, 6]
```

But, when I try to fetch keys via SCAN function

```
jedisConnection.scan(ScanOptions.NONE);
```

key somehow change to this

```
[-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 81, 114, 55, 49, 46, 61, -17, -65, -67, 82, 101, 74, 66, 6]
```

I'm confused, please tell me why are the keys different for `KEYS` and `SCAN`

Comment: Have you traversed through all the keys using SCAN ? SCAN returns only a few keys at a time.

Comment: Yeap... And for the test reason i used empty DB is Redis server, with just few keys.. So I'm not mixed up with another key, if you are talking about that..

Comment: Have your tried to skip `"*".getBytes()` to just `"*"`

Comment: Can you share some code? I'm not able to restore the UUID from the bytes or to understand what's going on. This behavior _might_ be serializer/byte-conversion related but I'm not fully sure about that.

Comment: No. Method `keys` receive only `byte[]`, not `String`. And i'm not sure the problem is there, because it returns everything fine..

Comment: @mp911de Sorry, it was first byte setted manually, for internal needs, i removed it.. Try restore again, if you'd fail - i'll share code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... Writing the answer in case if someone needs it.

First of all. Problem reproduced only when you got **custom** bytes array inside redis. If you'd save `byte[]` derived from `string` - everything would be ok.
After we calling `scan` method, Jedis inside itself receive bytes arrays bucket, creating new string instances from our bytes arrays, and there is a problem. Negative bytes transferring into *65533* value, and after transferring back to bytes arrays our primordial arrays are changed.

So, one of solutions - extend `Jedis`, `JedisConnection` and `JedisConnectionFactory` classes, where in `Jedis` make an analogue of method 'scan' without transferring `byte[]` to `string`